# Change label color when focus within a input

Tags: html, css, input, sass

```css
input {
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  color: black;
}

input:focus + label {
  color: red !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box d-flex flex-column">
  <label for="name" class="py-2">Your Name</label>
  <input class="py-2 border-0 text-white" id="name" type="text" />
</div>
```

I want to change the label text color, when i focus in a input of a form.

Comment: Just put label below input. And you are good to go

Comment: Wrap the input within the label and use `label:focus-within input`

Answer (score 3):

[**You can't select UP the DOM.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

What you can use is `:focus-within` on the wrapping div and then select downwards to the label..

```css
input {
  background: transparent;
}

label {
  color: black;
}

.input-box:focus-within label {
  color: red !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box d-flex flex-column">
  <label for="name" class="py-2">Your Name</label>
  <input class="py-2 border-0 text-white" id="name" type="text" />
</div>
```